# Unit Testing my MVC4 Controller Action Method where Session is checked for null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, session, nunit

I have started learning Unit Testing in MVC4 and having a project where i am trying to test using NUnit Framework for Test Cases. Here goes my Controller Action Method:

```
public ActionResult Edit(long id)
{
    if (Session["Admin"] != null)
    {
       tbl_Users objUser = new tbl_Users();
       objUser = objDBContext.tbl_Users.Find(id);
       if (objUser != null)
       {
            TempData["Edit"] = objUser;
            return PartialView("_Edit", objUser);
       }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Logout", "Home");
}
```

and Here is my Test class file where i wrote TestMethod to Test

```
[TestFixture]
public class AdminControllerTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Edit()
    {
        AdminController Admin = new AdminController();

        var id = Admin.Edit(3) as ViewResult;
        Assert.AreEqual("Edit", id.ViewName);
    }
}
```

Problem is, it call Action Method when i run in Debug mode, but it throws NullReference Exception since Session["Admin"] is null. Can anyone tell me how to Run above Test Method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can Mock the SessionState and the HttpContext for the controller like this:
(This code uses Moq)

```
using System.Web;
using Moq;

[TestFixture]
public class AdminControllerTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Edit()
    {
        var mockSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        mockSession.Setup(f => f["admin"]).Returns(()=> "yesToAdmin");
        var mockContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        mockContext.Setup(f => f.Session).Returns(mockSession.Object);

        AdminController admin = new AdminController();

        admin.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext()
        {
            Controller = admin,
            RequestContext = new RequestContext(mockContext.Object, new RouteData())
        };

        var id = admin.Edit(3) as ViewResult;
        Assert.AreEqual("Edit", id.ViewName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added MOQ reference from NUGET and even added namespace in my Test Project but i got this warning " the type or namespace name 'HttpSessionStateBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ". Tried to google but no result

Comment: Try adding a reference to System.Web, I'll update answer

Comment: That's what you are missing, a reference to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpsessionstatebase(v=vs.100).aspx .You need to check you have it referenced by your project as well as in the code. There are plenty of resources on SO and via google that will help you fix this.